# Twenty Seventeen Pages Loop

Tags: theme-development, loop

Can someone explain to me where in the Twenty Seventeen theme in the static homepage is it directed to do a loop of pages rather than posts?

I don't understand where it is doing this, from a fresh WordPress install.

In `front-page.php` I have this:

```
<?php
        // Get each of our panels and show the post data.
        if ( 0 !== twentyseventeen_panel_count() || is_customize_preview() ) : // If we have pages to show.

            /**
             * Filter number of front page sections in Twenty Seventeen.
             *
             * @since Twenty Seventeen 1.0
             *
             * @param $num_sections integer
             */
            $num_sections = apply_filters( 'twentyseventeen_front_page_sections', 4 );
            global $twentyseventeencounter;

            // Create a setting and control for each of the sections available in the theme.
            for ( $i = 1; $i < ( 1 + $num_sections ); $i++ ) {
                $twentyseventeencounter = $i;
                twentyseventeen_front_page_section( null, $i );
            }

    endif; // The if ( 0 !== twentyseventeen_panel_count() ) ends here. ?>
```

But where is the function code for the actual selection and output of these pages? I can't find it.

Furthermore, this code is after what looks like a loop searching for posts, but in the theme, the pages appear before a page labelled `Blog` that has the posts within it... what's that about?

I want to modify the theme to only pick certain pages so I'm interested in how it is generating the front page sections.

Comment: Are you talking about the Front Page Sections in the Customizer?

Comment: @Milo Maybe the same thing, I'm talking about the pages that appear on the homepage when Twenty Seventeen is set to a static homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page selection is set within the Customizer under Theme Options, which will only show when front page is set to static.

The output happens within the function `twentyseventeen_front_page_section` in the theme file `template-tags.php`, where each panel is queried individually with `get_post`, so it's not exactly a loop in the conventional sense.

You can change the number of sections from the default 4 with the `twentyseventeen_front_page_sections` filter, which should `return` the number of desired sections.

To access the values via code, you can use `get_theme_mod`, each panel is stored under the key `panel_$i`, where `$i` is the section number, starting at 1. The stored value is the ID of the page. You can also update these values with `set_theme_mod`.